# Handling questions that asks for a tool or a website

Tags: discussion, questions

While performing reviews, I sometimes encounter questions that ask for a software tool ***or a website*** to perform a task.

Here are 3 examples:

- [Browsing random page of a particular website](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/29969/browsing-random-page-of-a-particular-website)
- [Software/App to explain why police are blaring their sirens](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18250/is-there-a-site-or-app-that-will-tell-me-why-the-police-are-blaring-their-sirens)
- [App or site to make font-based clipart?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1963/app-or-site-to-make-font-based-clipart)

What is the best way to handle questions like these?

Answer (score 2):

They say "website" but they mean can also be called "webapp". A website to make a clipart is a webapp.

I think these questions are on-topic (at least 1st and 3rd).

The asker is looking for a software tool that will perform the task for them:

- On their OS, as a native tool
- Or via their browser

As a Linux user, sometimes I when I look for a particular tool I don't find it and end up using an online tool to perform what I want.

So I would say that asking for *a native tool or webapp* is OK.

Comment: I agree.  Do we have a working definition that we can use for the difference between a web site and a web app?

Comment: Actionable by the user or not, maybe? For example, a bunch of encyclopedia pages is a website. Something that allows me to search within these pages is a tool.

Comment: That's a possibility.  On the other hand, many websites have a search feature.  For example, is this SE a tool or a website?  What about Wikipedia?  I'm not sure how we draw the line.

Comment: "I am looking for an encyclopedia" is off-topic but "I am looking for a tool to search Wikipedia for a word+category" is on-topic, you will probably agree. Now, "I am looking for a 18th century philosophy encyclopedia with a search feature" is not too broad, and asks for an actionable tool, but in that case I would say off-topic because the "most difficult to fulfill" requirement is the data rather than the software.